# Printing without newline in Matlab

Tags: matlab, printing

How do I keep printing in the same line after every iteration? The **display** command takes the cursor to the next line by default each time it is called.

Comment: fprintf does not insert newlines unless you "\n"

Comment: You should never use `display` explicitly, it’s intended as an internal function. You should use `disp`, which might call `display` depending on the type of the input argument. `fprintf` is useful for more control over output, including newlines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example:

```
len = fprintf(1, repmat(' ', 1, 16));
for n=1:10
    fprintf(1, repmat('\b', 1, len));
    len = fprintf(1, '\t%d - %8.6f', n, rand());
    pause(1)
end
disp('\n');
```